# How to prefill fields on myetherwallet with given receiver address, amount, and gas limit?

Tags: dapps, myetherwallet

Assuming I have a DApp that relies on people having some injected Web3 available such as MetaMask. If I detect that they do not have Web3, how can I forward them to [myetherwallet offline transactions](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#offline-transaction) such that `To Address`, `Value`, and `Gas Limit` are prefilled?

What I mean is, it should look like this without users having to copy and paste the value, gas limit, and my address to send Ether from their account:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MyEtherWallet supports URI Strings on the Send Transaction Page.

- to=[address]
- value=[number]
- sendMode=[ether | token]
- tokenSymbol=[ARC | ICN | MKR | ....]
- gasLimit=[number] OR gas=[number]
- data=[hex data]

Example 1: https://www.myetherwallet.com/?to=0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8&value=1&tokenSymbol=REP&gaslimit=50000#send-transaction

Example 2: https://www.myetherwallet.com/?to=0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8&value=1&gaslimit=23000&data=0x5468616e6b20796f752c204d455720322e30#send-transaction

Comment: is value in wei or ether?

Comment: The value is just a value, if you enter 2, it will input 2 in the value/amount to send field. So you could say it's in Ether, but it works with tokens as well.

Comment: FYI, It was recently brought to my attention that these may or may not work in all cases anymore. I believe when things were updated for gasPrice or the custom gasLimits for ICOs or address-or-ENS-address-fields, things weren't properly updated. 

Comment: Does this also work for https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts as well? Can I specify the method and encoded data as well? Is there a documentation somewhere?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar you can use conteract.io for that purpose. For example, this link - https://conteract.io/c/86198dcd06?function=getAddr&AddrName=owner - will automatically init the `getAddr` function with *owner* as an argument of the function which is defined as `AddrName`.

Comment: I don't think this works at all anymore :(