# Get parameters for myetherwallet.com/#contracts

Tags: myetherwallet

Which parameters can I use to pre-fill the contract address and the parameters on https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts?

The answer in question [1] seems to be depreciated (I get an error) and does not focus on the subsite #contracts.

[1][How to prefill fields on myetherwallet with given receiver address, amount, and gas limit?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27909/how-to-prefill-fields-on-myetherwallet-with-given-receiver-address-amount-and)

Example from Myetherwallet (ADST):
address:
`0x422866a8F0b032c5cf1DfBDEf31A20F4509562b0`

ABI / JSON

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_bidValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getBuyPrice","outputs":[{"name":"tokenCount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"purchaseValue","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawnBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawFunds","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tradeSpreadInvert","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"crowdsaleEndDeclarationTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner2","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingUnlockFractionInvert","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"haltCrowdsale","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner1","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"confirmCrowdsaleEnd","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_maxPrice","type":"uint256"}],"name":"buyLimit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingUnlockPeriod","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"buy","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"unlockedBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenPriceMin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unlockFunds","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_askSizeTokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getSellPrice","outputs":[{"name":"saleValue","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"declareCrowdsaleEnd","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenCreationMin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingUnlockTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isHalted","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenCount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_minPrice","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sellLimit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"crowdsaleStartBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minFundingReached","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"crowdsaleEndLockTime","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_tokenCount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"sell","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owner1","type":"address"},{"name":"_owner2","type":"address"},{"name":"_withdrawAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"_crowdsaleStartBlock","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"who","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"purchaseValue","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"supplyAfter","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LogBuy","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"who","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"saleValue","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"supplyAfter","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LogSell","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LogWithdraw","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"completed","type":"bool"}],"name":"LogCrowdsaleEnd","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]
```

What I expect is a url such as e.g.
 https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts?to=0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8 so that the contract is already entered if I click on e.g. a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the code](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/blob/mercury/app/scripts/controllers/contractsCtrl.js#L20), it appears that the only URL parameter you can use is "address", but that seems not fully functional anyway. E.g. https://www.myetherwallet.com/?address=0x95D7321EdCe519419ba1DbC60A89bAfbF55EAC0D#contracts shows the ABI corresponding to that address (so the URL parameter worked), but the address field remains empty.

If you really want this functionality, I would suggest making the code change yourself and submitting a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conteract.io for that purpose. For example, this link - https://conteract.io/c/moataddress?function=getAddr&AddrName=owner - will automatically init the `getAddr` function with **owner** as an argument of the function which is defined as `AddrName`.